# Parse json map in Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have web service that returns json response like this

```
"map": [
        [
            0,
            "A mother of our mother"
        ],
        [
            2,
            "A brother of our father"
        ],
        [
            1,
            "A daughter of our sister"
        ]
    ],
```

How do i define data class to handle this response?

```
data class Map(
   @SerializedName("map")
   val map : <What type/class definition here>

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JSON represent array of objects array.

```
data class Map(
  @SerializedName("map")
  val map : List<List<Any?>>
)
```

Comment: I solved it with List<List<String>> because by default all parse as string. So i dont have to cast it again.

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like that:

```
data class Map(
    @SerializedName("map")
    val map : List<Collection<Any>>
)
```

I've been able to parse it with this test:

```
@Test
fun testJson() {
    val myMap = Gson().fromJson(json, Map::class.java)

    myMap.map.forEach { it ->
        println(it)
    }
    assert(myMap != null)
}
```

Remember to wrap your json with {} for the test

Comment: Right, i solved it using @Nitin Jain because at first i just confused with nested array. Thank you.